# find my bitcoin

Tags: buy-bitcoins, wallet-recovery

Again. I am not sure what to do and need help. Thank You for helping me. I have a paper receipt from a kiosk (atm) that says I purchased bitcoin. It is hard to read due to sitting. I was able to get my wallet from it. Looks like 33 characters. I have no idea what to do to find where this wallet is stored or the moneys, or is it even still valid. It is from 2015. Please Help. Thank You.
Coinoutlet Kiosk

Comment: What brand of ATM was it?

Comment: coinoutlet..../

Comment: Does it start with a 1 or 3?

Comment: it starts with   1

Comment: It's probably the bitcoin adress then. Check if it has any balance here -> https://blockchain.info/

Comment: Have you looked at http://coinoutletatm.com/coinoutletatm/ - it says you could have provided a wallet id to the ATM or it could create one for you.

Answer (score 1):

> **Looks like 33 characters**

That could be a bitcoin address. You cannot recover access to the Bitcoins at that address using only the address. To use those Bitcoins you need to know the private-key for that address.

It could also be a [Wallet-ID](https://bitcoin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001292411-What-is-the-difference-between-Bitcoin-wallet-ID-and-Bitcoin-wallet-address-). That would probably mean you have an online wallet where a third party (coinoutletatm.com in your case) controls your wallet. If so you should contact coinoutletatm.com to find out how you can use this Wallet-ID.
You can probably use it at any coinoutletatm.com Bitcoin-ATM. You may need to also remember a password and/or use a 2-factor-authentication method established at the time.

Currently coinoutlet.com don't seem to support wallets themselves, they expect you to get a wallet elsewhere and then use it with the ATM. [Their instructions](http://coinoutletatm.com/how-a-bitcoin-atm-works/) say

> ### Buying bitcoins
>
> Before you buy bitcoins, you first must get a wallet.  Wallet generating sites can help you do this, but the easiest option is to download a wallet app onto your phone from Coinbase, Blockchain.info or any other wallet from app store.
>
> With a wallet ready, hit the start key on the ATM screen and expose the wallet’s QR code to the machine’s scanner. And your address will appear on the screen.
>
> Insert the bills equivalent to the number of bitcoins you want to purchase. The exchange rate is displayed on the screen, as well as the amount you are about to purchase.
>
> By clicking on the send button, you will finish the transaction. You will receive a notification both on the ATM screen and your phone confirming reception of bitcoins into your wallet. Don’t forget to collect your receive.

If those are the instructions you followed, it is more likely that the receipt just shows the address of your wallet. You need to find your wallet. Your bitcoin-address is of no help in finding your wallet and cannot be used to regain control over your bitcoin.

---

> **is it even still valid. It is from 2015.**

The Bitcoins you purchased are probably still there unspent. So long as neither you nor anyone else moved the bitcoins elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

If you can import the wallet to yours it should be fine

Comment: For that, he'll need a private key presumably... I'm not sure he has one.